# WP8 Voice Recognition UI Causing unhandled exception

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, voice, voice-recognition

```
SpeechRecognizerUI sr = new SpeechRecognizerUI();
sr.Settings.ListenText = "Say the recipient and body of the E-Mail";
sr.Settings.ExampleText = "Mom saying Happy Mother's Day";
//await Speak("Say the recipient and body of the E-Mail"); // TTS prompt
var recoResult = await sr.RecognizeWithUIAsync();
MessageBox.Show(recoResult.RecognitionResult.Text);
```

This throws an unhandled exeption and the WP8 app crashes. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to **select a speech language** goto phone **SETTINGS** then **SPEECH**.

In my settings the speech language is listed as **none**, once I selected a language i.e. English (United States) it seems to work.

Refer to [**this post**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/d7eb2970-25e2-48e8-b7f7-52f68ac8aca0/the-parameter-is-incorrect-when-calling-new-speechrecognizerui)